# Button that add items to the listview

Tags: android, listview

I know this question has been floating all over the place, however I am unable to work this through even after going through all the posts and trying to understand. I am very new to developing apps in Android, so I definitely would need a lot of assistance. Anyways, I found some coding online that basically created a listview (the way I wanted with the layouts) and you could add items to the listview. Here's the code -

```
 ListView lv;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> feedList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_out);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CheckList);

    feedList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("item", "Item");
    map.put("qty", "Qty");
    map.put("tax", "Tax");
    map.put("total", "Total");
    feedList.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, feedList, R.layout.list_view_customs, new String[]{"item", "qty", "tax", "total"}, new int[]{R.id.textViewItem, R.id.textViewQty, R.id.textViewTax, R.id.textViewTotal});
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

As you can see that items are being added to the arraylist through the implementation of hashmaps and then the adapter is taking in the data arraylist to create a list view - which is set by the setAdapter functionality.

So, now since I wanted to populate the listview through a button click, I thought that this might work:

```
ListView lv;
Button addBanana;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> feedList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_out);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CheckList);
    addBanana = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddItem);

    feedList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("item", "Item");
    map.put("qty", "Qty");
    map.put("tax", "Tax");
    map.put("total", "Total");
    feedList.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, feedList, R.layout.list_view_customs, new String[]{"item", "qty", "tax", "total"}, new int[]{R.id.textViewItem, R.id.textViewQty, R.id.textViewTax, R.id.textViewTotal});
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        addBanana.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         map.put("item", "Banana");
         map.put("qty", "1");
         map.put("tax", "0.13");
         map.put("total", "1.13");
         feedList.add(map);
         simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

}

It builds up perfectly. But when I try to go to this activity by clicking a button (which is in the main activity), the screen turns dark and says to quit .. So, I am not sure what is wrong with this approach. I know there is definitely something wrong with the way I am handling the adapters ... So, any feedbacks would be nice.. Thanks a lot!

Also, if you need the XML's, please let me know!

Comment: try this and see if it will work, instead of `simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` initialise it again with the new set of object data and see if you will have the same sequence of events, i never seem to use `SimpleAdapter` because i never had the opportunity to add stuff at runtime with this `SimpleAdapter.add(object o)` because it never existed.. that was back when i started, never used it again.

Comment: Yeah no change there ...